# Чем отличается слово "гололёд" от "гололедица"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Смотрю прогноз погоды, где ведущая поясняет:"Завтра в целом по стране ожидается гололёд, местами - гололедица..." 
   В чём разница между этими словами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Гололёд
Слой льда на поверхности земли, на деревьях, проводах и т.п., образующийся при замерзании на них капель дождя, мороси; состояние погоды при образовании такого слоя льда.

Гололедица
Слой льда на поверхности земли, образующийся при похолодании после оттепели; состояние погоды при образовании такого слоя льда.

Как видим, в словарях указано, что гололедица образуется только на поверхности земли, в отличие от гололёда, и у них разные условия образования.

Более подробная информация - из Большой советской энциклопедии:

Гололёд — слой **плотного** льда, образующийся на поверхности земли и на предметах (стволах и ветвях деревьев, телеграфных проводах и т.д.) при замерзании на них переохлажденных капель тумана или дождя (с температурой ниже 0° С). Обычно Г. наблюдается при температурах воздуха от 0 до -3°С, но иногда и более низких. Образуется Г. преимущественно с наветренной стороны предметов. Корка намёрзшего льда может достичь толщины нескольких см и вызвать обламывание сучьев, обрыв проводов, погубить посевы.

Гололед — слой **плотного** льда, образующийся на земной поверхности и на предметах (деревьях, проводах, домах и т. д.) **при намерзании капель** переохлажденного дождя и мороси, обычно при температуре воздуха от 0 до -3 °С.

Гололедица — **тонкий** слой льда на поверхности земли, образующийся после оттепели или дождя в результате похолодания, а также замерзания мокрого снега, капель дождя.

Ключевое отличие в том, что **гололедица образуется не везде, а местами - там, где была влага (лужи от дождя или таяния снега), а гололёд образуется вcюду (равномерно) - во время выпадения дождя, капли которого быстро замерзают на всей поверхности**.

Здесь указаны особенности употребления слов синоптиками, а также подробнее про сами явления и их последствия:
http://dpchs.donland.ru/Default.aspx?pageid=48432

Answer (score 2):

Гололед и гололедица - совершенно разные понятия. Первое - явление природы, второе - ее состояние.

Гололедица - это лед на поверхности, который появляется при понижении температуры в результате замерзания воды образовавшейся при таянии снега и льда во время оттепели. При колебаниях температуры около нуля гололедица бывает довольно часто.

Гололед - это образование льда на земле, деревьях, проводах и пр., связанное с замерзанием дождя, выпадающего на холодную поверхность. Чаще всего гололед возникает при резком потеплении из изморози, когда теплый воздух проходит над сильно охлажденной поверхностью. Это значительно более редкое и опасное явление, особенно для энергетиков и автомобилистов, так как трудно предсказывается, обычно быстро и интенсивно развивается. В прогнозе погоды мы слышим: "гoлoлед, на дopoгах гoлoледица".

Comment: В целом, ответ неплохой, смущает второе предложение. В вашем же тексте о гололедице написано:"появляется при понижении температуры", то есть, является.